# Как сделать чтобы бот отправлял рандомное фото, Aiogram

Tags: aiogram

у меня такая проблема, как сделать чтобы бот отправил рандомное фото из папки Welcome?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])   
async def hshshd(message: types.Message): 
    photo = open('Welcome/' + random.choice(os.listdir('Welcome')), 'rb') 
    await message.reply(photo)
```

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, смог сделать сам

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])
async def hshshd(message: types.Message):
    photo = open('ava/' + random.choice(os.listdir('ava')), 'rb')
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```